# How to import and display a road network in XML to ArcGis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, convert, network, xml

I am trying to convert xml data to shapefile features using ArcGis 10.1.

Im using the open source SUMO traffic simulation software. Part of the model process is to convert OpenStreetMap road network data to an readable xml format.

The xml format describes the "lanes" between nodes in the network. The below example is for a straight horizontal road/edge with 2 lanes between nodes "A" and "B". The length is in meters, and the "shape" give the start/end X and Y co-ords on a basic XY grid.

```
<edge id="AtoB" from="A" to="B" priority="-1">
        <lane id="AtoB_0" index="0" speed="13.90" length="50.00" shape="0.00,51.65 50.00,51.65"/>
</edge>
<edge id="BtoA" from="B" to="A" priority="-1">
        <lane id="BtoA_0" index="0" speed="13.90" length="50.00" shape="50.00,48.35 0.00,48.35"/>
</edge>
```

Ideally I would be able to generate shapefile features for each lane in the network. Also the above example is for a test I am conducting and is not spatially referenced, for the end network I will use WGS 84.